# I’m using MLkit and would like to have the returned raw values into a Dropbox/combo box

Tags: android, dart, flutter, firebase-mlkit

I’m using MLkit and would like to have the returned raw values into a Dropbox/combo box. Currently I have them listed.

Please see the code below:

```
return Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            itemCount: barcodes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              var text;

              final barcode = barcodes[i];
              switch (widget._scannerType) {
                case BARCODE_SCANNER:
                  VisionBarcode res = barcode as VisionBarcode;
                  text = "Detected Attribute: ${res.rawValue}";
                  break;
                case LABEL_SCANNER:
                  VisionLabel res = barcode as VisionLabel;
                  text = "Detected Attribute: ${res.label}";
                  break;
              }
return _buildTextRow(text);

Widget _buildTextRow(text) {
return ListTile(
  title: Text(
    "$text",
  ),
  dense: true,
);
}
```